# Efficient way to creating a Term Frequency Matrix from a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, word-frequency

Given a pandas data frame with 2 columns - column 1 is the user name, and column 2 is the content linked to the user.

[image]

How does one create a Term Frequency Matrix that looks like the following?

[image]

My attempt:
[image]

So it seems like this is working, but I want it to show column and row names in the final matrix form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you convert it to a dataframe again?

`pd.DataFrame(X.toarray(), columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names_out())`